# Wicked PDF generation error in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I'm using WickedPDF in my Rails app to generate PDF files. It's working great on my local machine. In production I'm seeing the following error in my log:

```
Started GET "/financieel/facturen/2.pdf" for 81.205.74.167 at 2012-09-19 14:58:37 +0200
  Processing by InvoicesController#show as PDF
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
***************WICKED***************
Rendered invoices/show.pdf.haml (6.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in show'
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:17:in `show'
```

In invoices_controller.rb there's nothing unusual:

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: 'factuur'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this line, where wicked_pdf tries to guess where your wkhtmltopdf binary is, is causing your trouble: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L207

If wkhtmltopdf is actually installed on the server, probably the best thing to do is specifically set your path to wkhtmltopdf in an initializer like so:

```
# config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb
WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => '/opt/bin/wkthmltopdf' } # or wherever it actually is
```

Comment: By default WickedPDF is searching for /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf. I installed it in /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf and setup a symlink to /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.

Also, generating PDF files from the rails console is working excellent.

Comment: It's fixed now! I compiled it from source. Apparently the latest code in his git repository works. Changing the exe_path to the new binary fixes it.